# One to One and Onto functions

Tags: functions

The third function of this problem is a mystery to me.

[image: One to one and Onto functions]

I think I understand the other three.

For the first one, you're mapping an ordered pair into the set of integers. This function is onto because the image of f is the entire set **Z**. It isn't one to one because you can arrive at the same f(n,m) with different pairs of n and m. For instance the image of f(1,1) is 0 and f(2,2) is also 0.

The function g is one to one and onto while the function k is only onto.

The function h is given me some trouble. My book claims that it is onto but I don't understand how that can be. For any pair (n,m) the result will end up being n / ( m / 0)

which can be rewritten as n * 0 / m.

In other words, any element of the product set **Z** x (**Z**/0) will map to 0 on the set **Q** which is neither one to one or onto.

Comment: Do you understand what $\mathbb Z \setminus 0$ means? See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have misinterpreted $\mathbb{Z} \setminus 0$.  Note the direction of the slash.  It is not the set of integers divided by $0$.  It is the set of integers with $0$ removed.  $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ might have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that:**

$1]$ $h(4,6)=4/6=2/3=h(2,3)$ but $(4,6)\neq(2,3)$.

$2] $ $h$ is onto by definition.